# Properties file read java and putting result to string

Tags: java, string, properties

I have been coding a chat program with login, but to transfer username from login class to chat class I'm using .properties file. And I want to get

```
prop.getProperty("username")
```

into string so I do

```
String user=prop.getProperty("login");
```

And it doesn't work. so I did

```
System.out.println(user);
```

and it prints me out

```
null
```

Any ideas? Thanks for help.

Full code :

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;


    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("user.properties");

        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);

        // get the property value and print it out
        String user=prop.getProperty("login");
        System.out.println(user);
        //System.out.println(prop.getProperty("username"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And users.properties file:

```
#xxxx----xxxx
#Thu Jul 31 13:14:16 CEST 2014
username=ladi
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". Where's the property file located? What's in the property file? Do you get any exceptions? There's not much information to go on yet.

Comment: Show your 'user.properties' too.

Comment: input = new FileInputStream("user.properties"); -- Path of user.properties is correct? Any FileNotFoundException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only property I can see in your property file is 'username', so your example code won't work, as you are trying to get the value of a property named 'login'. If you want to get the usename referenced by a string typed variable you should use

```
String user = prop.getProperty("username");
```

I hope that helps.